# Boot loop after flashing Android 6.0 Marshmallow on my Nexus 5

Tags: rom-flashing, nexus-5, installation, flashtool, 6.0-marshmallow

I had Android Lollipop installed on my Nexus 5 (Was Rooted, had TWRP and MultiROM installed) and wanted to simply start fresh with new clean install of Marshmallow.

So I followed the instructions (step 1 to 6): https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en

After running the flash-all script the device rebooted I see the Marshmallow boot animation but it has been running for 45 minutes. Is this normal?

Is there any suggestions beside reflashing because I've tried 3 times with the same results (45 minutes is the longest I've waited).

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

OK the problem was that I used the wrong version of fastboot. It was already installed on my Mac so when I was running the flash-all script it was actually running the system version.

So I modified the script to make sure the path to fastboot was actually pointing to the good version.

And voilà, it took about 7 minutes after reboot.

Comment: what do you mean by running _the system version_? and what is your "good" version? more details please

Comment: follow up question [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125210/boot-loop-after-flashing-android-6-0-marshmallow-on-nexus-5-follow-up)

Comment: @abbood the version of fastboot was not the latest. I was using the old version that was already present on my mac. When running the script it was this old version that was used instead of the new one I've had downloaded. Using the latest version solved the boot loop problem for me.