# Boot loop after flashing Android 6.0 Marshmallow on Nexus 5

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rom-flashing, boot-loop, nexus-5

This question follows up on [Boot loop after flashing Android 6.0 Marshmallow on my Nexus 5](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125192/boot-loop-after-flashing-android-6-0-marshmallow-on-my-nexus-5) (but there are many other posts about this topic on the web, see [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/3d47vq/help_nexus_5_stuck_on_four_spinning_dots_loading/) and this [XDA Developers post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/guide-to-fix-persist-partition-t2821576)).

I just want to approach this problem in a more structured way as opposed to just saying how something worked by coincidence.

### Problem definition

Like everyone else, I simply followed the official instructions [from Google developers](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images). To expand a bit (because this could be the cause of the problem), following this part of the instruction from the above link:

> To flash a device using one of the system images below (or one of your own), you need the fastboot tool. You can get the fastboot tool either:
>
> - From a compiled version of the Android Open Source Project.
> - Or, from the platform-tools/ directory in the Android SDK. Be sure that you have the latest version of the Android SDK Platform-tools from the SDK Manager.

So I simply downloaded the entire [Android Studio application](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (I know that's a bit of overkill but I just wanted to make sure I got the latest and greatest).

From the below Android Studio screenshot, you can see that I have Android SDK Platform-Tools 23.0.1.

[image]

**Question:** I'm updating my phone from Android 5.0.x (not sure what the exact version is). Could it be that this Android version mismatches the Android platform-tools that I have?

I've ensured that my `fastboot` is added to my `PATH` environment:

```
$ which fastboot
/Users/abdullahbakhach/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/fastboot
```

I've downloaded the flash file (specifically the hammerhead for Android 6.0.0 (MRA58K)), then I started the device in fastboot mode by the key combination, and ran the `flash-all` script.

What happened was that the script ran with the following logs:

```
$ ./flash-all.sh 
sending 'bootloader' (3120 KB)...
OKAY [  0.207s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  0.524s]
finished. total time: 0.731s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.001s]
finished. total time: 0.001s
sending 'radio' (45425 KB)...
OKAY [  1.536s]
writing 'radio'...
OKAY [  3.145s]
finished. total time: 4.681s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.001s]
finished. total time: 0.001s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: HHZ12k
Baseband Version.....: M8974A-2.0.50.2.27
Serial Number........: 03a3d66d0a4e64bd
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
OKAY [  0.100s]
checking version-bootloader...
OKAY [  0.100s]
checking version-baseband...
OKAY [  0.100s]
sending 'boot' (9156 KB)...
OKAY [  0.500s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.798s]
sending 'recovery' (10016 KB)...
OKAY [  0.562s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.850s]
sending 'system' (1019261 KB)...
OKAY [ 32.164s]
writing 'system'...
OKAY [ 70.421s]
erasing 'userdata'...
OKAY [ 15.854s]
erasing 'cache'...
OKAY [  0.630s]
rebooting...

finished. total time: 122.480s
```

**Question:** should I be concerned about this part?

```
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
```

Anyways after all is done, the phone reboots and gets stuck on the boot screen (forever).

### What I've tried

I've tried running these commands as suggested by [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/guide-to-fix-persist-partition-t2821576)

```
adb shell
e2fsck /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/persist
```

and

```
make_ext4fs /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/persist
```

but nothing changed.

I've also tried performing a wipe using TWRP as suggested by this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/3d47vq/help_nexus_5_stuck_on_four_spinning_dots_loading/):

- I downloaded the twrp-2.8.7.1-hammerhead.dmg file from the [twrp site](https://twrp.me/devices/lgnexus5.html)

and then ran

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp-2.8.7.1-hammerhead.dmg
```

then performed a wipe two different ways:

- performing a normal wipe pretty much made things worse. The phone would show the Google logo then reboot, show the Google logo and so on.
- simply deleting the cache also didn't make any difference at all.

I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I too faced this issue and issuing the fastboot commands manually (instead of relying on `flash-all`) and it worked well.

These are the commands to use (just forget everything and make sure these commands are executed in this order with the appropriate .img file available):

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash cache cache.img
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot reboot
```

Comment: mmm.. i just tried that.. it seems to still be stuck on that load screen.. how long did it take before it finally booted properly for you?

Comment: it actually worked! it just took it a bit to reboot (tip: how do you know that this time it will work? i noticed that the screen wasn't as dimmed as those times it usually fails.. also i advise you not to wait for it.. put your phone somewhere else and go on with your business)

Comment: Yeah, sorry to leave you to find it yourself. It took me more than five minutes to cross the marshmallow boot animation.

Comment: Thanks guys. By the time I got this far reading the thread the startup finished successfully. :)

Comment: On Nexus 9 I've also got `vendor.img`, and I have no `userdata.img`. Do you know at which moment to flash the former and why there is no latter?

Comment: See this [Link](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/12/running-into-the-dreaded-missing-system-img-error-flashing-android-5-0-factory-images-heres-how-to-get-around-it/), where it is explained why Nexus9 differs. By the way how could we address you, when we can't type your name?

Comment: @Narayanan if you just type '@' into the empty comment box, it should offer to complete it for you. Other than that, copy & paste...

Comment: Thanks @derobert I am aware. I just want to keep that user informed that having a non-English name makes things difficult (just a suggestion to consider). I guess the site allows only one @. And I found it super difficult when I had copy and paste using a mobile keyboard.